# unable to create hive table with primary key

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I am unable to create an external table in hive with primary key. Following is the example code:

```
hive> create table exmp((name string),primary key(name));
```

This returns me the following error message:

> NoViableAltException(278@[]) at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser_IdentifiersParser.identifier(HiveParser_IdentifiersParser.java:11216) at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.identifier(HiveParser.java:35977)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.columnNameType(HiveParser.java:31169)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.columnNameTypeList(HiveParser.java:29373)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.createTableStatement(HiveParser.java:4439)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.ddlStatement(HiveParser.java:2084)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.execStatement(HiveParser.java:1344)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.statement(HiveParser.java:983)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.ParseDriver.parse(ParseDriver.java:190)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compile(Driver.java:434)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compile(Driver.java:352)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compileInternal(Driver.java:995)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.runInternal(Driver.java:1038)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:931)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:921)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLocalCmd(CliDriver.java:268)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processCmd(CliDriver.java:220)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLine(CliDriver.java:422)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.executeDriver(CliDriver.java:790)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:684)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:623)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:212) FAILED: ParseException line 1:18 cannot recognize input near '(' 'name'
>   'string' in column specification

Please help me out.

Comment: Hive does not have primary keys.

Comment: Correct me if i am wrong, i am encountering data loss while sqoop merge without the primary key in the hive table.

Comment: Sqoop handles merge keys independently of the Hive table definition so there is no need (or capability) to assign a primary key to a Hive table for this purpose. If you're having Sqoop merge issues then that's a different question altogether.

Comment: Primary keys appear in Hive starting from Hive version 2.1.0. Before Hive version 2.1.0, trying to use `PRIMARY KEY` will result in an error.
[Source](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-13290)

Answer (score 12):

Older version of the hive doesn't support primary key but this support has been added in 2.1.0 version of hive. So here is the sample query for it

`CREATE TABLE table_name (
  id int,
  name string,
  dept string,
  primary key(id) disable novalidate
);`

PS: How to get the version of hive

`hive --version
 Hive 1.2.1000.x.x.x.xxxx-x`

OR enter into beeline and hit

`beeline
 Beeline version 1.2.1000.x.x.x.xxxx-x by Apache Hive`

Answer (score 4):

Sorry there is no primary key in hive if you have any other functionality related to hive table got through this

```
CREATE DATABASE [IF NOT EXISTS] userdb;

SHOW DATABASES;

DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS userdb;

DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS userdb CASCADE;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS employee ( eid int, name String,
 salary String, destination String)
 COMMENT "Employee details"
 ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
 FIELDS TERMINATED BY "\t"
 LINES TERMINATED BY "\n"
 STORED AS TEXTFILE;  

LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH '/home/user/sample.txt'
    OVERWRITE INTO TABLE employee;

ALTER TABLE employee RENAME TO emp;

desc tablename;

ALTER TABLE employee CHANGE name ename String;
hive> ALTER TABLE employee CHANGE salary salary Double;

ALTER TABLE employee ADD COLUMNS ( 
    dept STRING COMMENT 'Department name');    

ALTER TABLE employee REPLACE COLUMNS ( 
    eid INT empid Int, 
    ename STRING name String);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS employee;

SHOW TABLES;

SELECT * FROM employee WHERE Salary>40000 && Dept=TP;  

CREATE VIEW emp_30000 AS
    SELECT * FROM employee
    WHERE salary>30000;

DROP VIEW emp_30000;
```

Answer (score 3):

From official Page : https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL

They have included in the syntax to create table as:

```
constraint_specification:
  : [, PRIMARY KEY (col_name, ...) DISABLE NOVALIDATE ]
    [, CONSTRAINT constraint_name FOREIGN KEY (col_name, ...) REFERENCES 
table_name(col_name, ...) DISABLE NOVALIDATE .
```

So that means we can create table with primary keys in hive

Version information

As of Hive 2.1.0 (HIVE-13290).

Hive includes support for non-validated primary and foreign key constraints. 
Some SQL tools generate more efficient queries when constraints are present. 
Since these constraints are not validated, an upstream system needs to ensure 
data integrity before it is loaded into Hive.
Example:

```sql
CREATE TABLE pk(
    id1 integer,
    id2 integer,
    primary key(id1, id2) disable novalidate
);

CREATE TABLE fk(
    id1 integer,
    id2 integer,
    constraint c1 foreign key(id1, id2) references pk(id2, id1) disable novalidate
);
```

Answer (score 0):

We don't have any primary key and foreign key in hive.So remove the primary key and execute.

create table exmp(name string);

Answer (score 0):

First, derby in hive not have key
Second, some key may duplicate with keyword in hive show you have to add single quote to them.
For my case, i get error with query

```
  create table NYSE (exchange String,stock_symbol String,stock_date String,stock_price_open double, stock_price_high double, stock_price_low double, stock_price_close double, stock_volume double, stock_price_adj_close double) row format delimited fields terminated by ‘,’;
```

it should be

```
  create table NYSE (`exchange` String,stock_symbol String,stock_date String,stock_price_open double, stock_price_high double, stock_price_low double, stock_price_close double, stock_volume double, stock_price_adj_close double) row format delimited fields terminated by ',';
```

Answer (score -1):

There is no primary key concept in Hive as it is not a database and in hive operation is file based not the record based.

Try this

```
create table table_name (
    row_number() over() as rowId     operation
    name string,
    age Int,
    address string) row format delimited fields terminated by ',' stored as textfile;
```

Here consider `rowId` as unique and perform the operation.

Answer (score -4):

Try this

```
create table exmp(name string,primary key(name));
```