# I have a MYSQL table creation query containing the following constraint KEY `ix_email_address` (`address`) . How can I implement this in hive?

Tags: hadoop, hive, bigdata, hql

KEY `ix_email_address` (`address`) how to implement the MySQL constraint in Hive ?

Comment: what does this command do in MYSQL?

Answer (score 0):

Hive doesn't contain any primary/foreign key notions. You need to find another way to implement those constraints. Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28537042/unable-to-create-hive-table-with-primary-key).